# Indexed variable in AMPL

Tags: ampl

I have the following model with a variable that is a value from a vector (index of p in objective function)

But AMPL displays an error: subscript variables are not yet allowed.

How can I do to implement this kind of addressing in objective function?

Thanks in advance and best regards.
Gabriel

```
param dimension;                


set T:={1..dimension};          
set O:={0};                     
set V:= O union T;                      
param c{i in V, j in V};        
param p{i in V};                                

set ady{i in V} within V := {j in V : i<>j and c[i,j] <> -1} ;    



# Variables 

var x{i in V, j in V}                         binary;   
var u{i in V}                                 integer;      


# Objective
minimize costo: sum{i in V, j in V}   p[u[i]-1] *  x[i,j] * c[i,j];

# Constraints


s.t. grado_a     {j in V}          : sum{i in ady[j] : j <> i} x[i,j] = 1; 

s.t. grado_b     {i in V}          : sum{j in ady[i] : i <> j} x[i,j] = 1; 

s.t. origen      {i in O}          : u[i] = 0;  

s.t. sigo_1      {i in T}          : u[i] >=1;

s.t. sigo_2      {i in T}          : u[i] <= card(V) -1;

s.t. precedencia {i in T, j in T : i <> j}  : u[i] - u[j] + 1  <= (card(V) - 1)*(1 - x[i,j]) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

AMPL doesn't allow variables in subscripts yet. However, the [ilogcp](http://www.ampl.com/NEW/LOGIC/#ilogcp) driver for AMPL supports the `element` constraint, for example:

```
include cp.ampl;
minimize costo:
  sum{i in V, j in V} element({v in V} p[v], u[i] - 1) *  x[i,j] * c[i,j];
```

where `element({v in V} p[v], u[i] - 1)` is equivalent to `p[u[i] - 1]` and is translated into an `IloElement` constraint.